# route to application stopped working in OpenShift Online 3.9

Tags: openshift, openshift-online

I have an application running in Openshift Online starter, which worked for the last 5 months. A single pod behind a service with a route defined that does edge tls termination.

Since Saturday, when trying to access the application, I get the error message

> Application is not available
>   The application is currently not serving requests at this endpoint. It may not have been started or is still starting.
>
> Possible reasons you are seeing this page:
>
> The host doesn't exist. Make sure the hostname was typed correctly and that a route matching this hostname exists.
>
> The host exists, but doesn't have a matching path. Check if the URL path was typed correctly and that the route was created using the desired path.
>
> Route and path matches, but all pods are down. Make sure that the resources exposed by this route (pods, services, deployment configs, etc) have at least one pod running.

The pod is running, I can exec into it and check this, I can port-forward to it and access it.

checking the different components with `oc`:

```
$ oc get po -o wide
NAME              READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       IP             NODE
taboo3-23-jt8l8   1/1       Running   0          1h        10.128.37.90   ip-172-31-30-113.ca-central-1.compute.internal

$ oc get svc
NAME      CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
taboo3    172.30.238.44   <none>        8080/TCP   151d

$ oc describe svc taboo3
Name:           taboo3
Namespace:      sothawo
Labels:         app=taboo3
Annotations:        openshift.io/generated-by=OpenShiftWebConsole
Selector:       deploymentconfig=taboo3
Type:           ClusterIP
IP:         172.30.238.44
Port:           8080-tcp    8080/TCP
Endpoints:      10.128.37.90:8080
Session Affinity:   None
Events:         <none>

$ oc get route
NAME              HOST/PORT                                                             PATH      SERVICES   PORT       TERMINATION     WILDCARD
taboo3            taboo3-sothawo.193b.starter-ca-central-1.openshiftapps.com                      taboo3     8080-tcp   edge/Redirect   None
```

I tried to add a new route as well (with or without tls), but am getting the same error.

Does anybody have an idea what might be causing this and how to fix it?

**Addition April 17, 2018**: Got an email from Openshift Online support:

> It looks like you may be affected by this [bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1567532).

So waiting for it to be resolved.

Comment: Try doing this: ``oc scale --replicas=0 dc <deploymentconfig>`` and then ``oc scale --replicas=1 dc <deploymentconfig>``. Replace ``<deploymentconfig>`` with actual deployment config name. A feature relating to idle inactive apps was recently turned on and is possible that is causing the issue. Scaling down and then scaling up to manually reset idle state may work. https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/admin_guide/idling_applications.html#idling-applications-unidling-applications

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton alas that did not work; I had tried that from the Web Console before, down- and upscaling neither via web or cli changes anything.

Comment: Issue is currently being investigated by operations team for OpenShift.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but this has possibly been fixed up now, so try and see if things are working.

Comment: How to expose openshift project as url or to connect via Postman? (I need to interact with project through postman to create kafka source connector)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

The problem has been resolved by Openshift Online, the application is working again

Comment: Can you elaborate what solved the issue?